# Bound on height of a tree

Tags: tree, nodes, theory

I need some help understanding the following question: I couldn't get LaTeX to work, sorry.

Assume some tree has the property that

```
n <= 2^(h^1/5))

//LaTeX code beflow
n \geq 2^{h^{1/5}}
```

where n is the number of nodes in a tree and h is the height of the tree. Give a bound on the height h of the tree in terms of the number of its nodes n.

Here is what I was thinking, I'm not exactly sure if this is correct or not.

```
ln(n) >= h^(1/5)*ln(2)
ln(n)^5 = h*ln(2)
ln(n)^5 = h*c
h = ln(n)^5
```

Comment: Math error in the second step, but you're on the right track. This will just change c.

Comment: Ah, ln(2) would also have to be to the fifth root correct? But as you said, it just changes c.